# How to find and return multiple values using "text contains" filter in cell?

Tags: python, google-sheets

[image]

I am trying to return the values horizontally from the "FILE_ID" if "Criteria" column text contains the following value. Adjacent to the "FILE_ID column, since the "Criteria" column values do not match, the index/match formulas were problematic.

This is what I have so far:

[to return value for Pic 1}

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, A2:B150, 2)
```

[to return value for, Pic 2, etc}

```
=If(VLOOKUP(B2, A2:B150, 2)=C2), (VLOOKUP(B2, A2:B150, 2), '")
```

Example:

If the Criteria is the following (1.108.1-):
[image: 2]

For returning a value for Pic 2, rather than looping the array for each Pic column, I attempted to use conditional logic but failed. Additionally, I have an idea for concatenating text into single line string using SQL or Google Sheets, but I don't know how to return multiple values per single criteria. Any advice or critique to this approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea of how you might achieve this with pandas in python, but I'm not sure of how you would do it exclusively in google sheets or excel.

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'your_file_name.xlsx' 
sheet_name = 'specific_sheet_name'
alldata = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=sheet_name)  # Read the Excel file into a DataFrame
list_of_dicts = []  # Initialize an empty list to store dictionaries

# Iterate over each value in the 'Criteria' column
for criteria in alldata['Criteria']:
    new_dict = {}  # Initialize a new dictionary for each criteria
    pic_number = 1  # Initialize the picture number

    # Iterate over each value in the 'FILE_ID' column
    for id in alldata['FILE_ID']:
        if str(criteria) in str(id):  # Check if the criteria is present in the FILE_ID
            new_dict[f"Pic {pic_number}"] = id  # Add the FILE_ID to the dictionary with the corresponding picture number
            pic_number += 1  # Increment the picture number

    list_of_dicts.append(new_dict)  # Append the dictionary to the list

pic_numbers = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)  # Convert the list of dictionaries into a DataFrame
pic_numbers.to_excel('new_file_name.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)  # Write the DataFrame to a new Excel file
```

If you export the google sheet you showed in your screenshot, save it in a folder with this script, and then run this script, it should make a new excel/sheets compatible file that has the table you're looking for in its Sheet1.

That is of course assuming that you have a python interpreter and pandas installed.

You can probably make it much more efficient, and it will probably break if there are more criteria than there are File IDs, but I think it'll get the job you've described done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this formula in C2:

```
=IF(B2="","",TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A:A,INDEX(ISNUMBER(B2,A:A)))))
```

It should filter all column B according to if B2 is found (with SEARCH) and return those values transported as a row instead of a column

Then just drag it down. There could be ways of doing it with an array formula, but it would be recommendable if you have always the same amount of files per code